# Mounting 4TB WD Green via docking station to Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: hard-drive, mount

I always get this error message:

> Error mounting /dev/sda2 at /media/pi/PIHDD: Command-line `mount -t
>   "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sda2"
>   "/media/pi/PIHDD"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: wrong
>   fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda2,
>        missing codepage or helper program, or other error
>
> ```
>    In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
>    dmesg | tail or so.
> ```

And I really don't know how I should solve this problem. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Have you checked the syslog as advised (`dmesg | tail` in your terminal)? Is there any relevant output there?

Comment: Is the hard disc really formatted with NTFS? Can you mount the hard disc with Windows?

Comment: What kind of docking station? USB? How do you supply the HDD with power?

Comment: I guess you are using `raspbian`. Can you please add a proper tag? You are trying to mount a Microsoft `ntfs` file system. I suspect there is a problem with its driver. With `journalctl -e` you should get more information. Please edit your question and give us the output from `apt list ntfs-3g` and `grep ntfs /proc/filesystems`.